# Keyboard with rc.local

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, python-3, keyboard

I Have written this python program for my pi.

```
print("CC ACTIVATED")
import lcddriver
import time
import subprocess
display = lcddriver.lcd()
try:
    display.lcd_display_string("CC... ", 1) 
    time.sleep(2)
    display.lcd_display_string("ONLINE", 2)
    time.sleep(2)
    display.lcd_clear()
except Exception:
    print("SCREEN ERROR")
try:
    display.lcd_display_string("SETUP A", 1) 
    display.lcd_display_string("PASWORD? Y/N", 2)
except Exception:
    print("SCREEN ERROR")
activate = input("")
if activate == 'y':
    print("ACTIVATED")
    try:
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("", 1) 
        time.sleep(2)
        display.lcd_display_string("LOADING", 2)
        time.sleep(2)
        display.lcd_clear()
    except Exception:
        print("SCREEN ERROR")
else:
    print("ABORT")
    try:
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("", 1) 
        time.sleep(2)
        display.lcd_display_string("ABORT", 2)
        time.sleep(2)
        display.lcd_clear()
        subprocess.call(["sudo","halt"])
    except Exception:
        print("SCREEN ERROR")
        subprocess.call(["sudo","halt"])
k = True
while k:
    
    try:
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("ENTER PASWORD", 1) 
        display.lcd_display_string("----------------", 2)
    except Exception:
        print("SCREEN ERROR")
    pasword = input("")
    display.lcd_clear()
    try:
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("YOU TYPED:", 1) 
        display.lcd_display_string(pasword, 2)
        time.sleep(2)
        display.lcd_display_string("CONFIRM? Y/N", 1) 
    except Exception:
        print("SCREEN ERROR")
    ok = input("")
    if ok == 'y':
        k = False
    else:
        display.lcd_clear()
try:
    display.lcd_clear()
    display.lcd_display_string("PASWORD", 1) 
    display.lcd_display_string("SET", 2)
except Exception:
    print("SCREEN ERROR")
time.sleep(2)
run = True
try:
    display.lcd_clear()
    display.lcd_display_string("STARTING ", 1) 
    display.lcd_display_string("GAME...", 2)
except Exception:
    print("SCREEN ERROR")

while run:
    try:
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("ENTER PASWORD ", 1) 
        display.lcd_display_string("TO DEACTIVATE", 2)
    except Exception:
        print("SCREEN ERROR")
    pasword1 = input("")
    if pasword1 == pasword:
        try:
            display.lcd_clear()
            display.lcd_display_string("PASWORD....", 1)
            time.sleep(2)
            display.lcd_display_string("ACCEPTED", 2)
            time.sleep(2)
            display.lcd_clear()
            display.lcd_display_string("DEACTIVATED", 2)
            subprocess.call(["sudo","halt"])
            time.sleep(10)
        except Exception:
            print("SCREEN ERROR")
            subprocess.call(["sudo","halt"])
    else:
        try:
            display.lcd_clear()
            display.lcd_display_string("PASWORD....", 1)
            time.sleep(2)
            display.lcd_display_string("UNACCEPTED", 2)
            time.sleep(2)
        except Exception:
            print("SCREEN ERROR")
```

It works perfectly fine whenever I run it in the terminal or Idle. However I want it to run when the pi boots up. This is the inside of my rc.local file.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
python3 /home/pi/lcd/CC.py

exit 0
```

The program starts, but when I try to type something into the keyboard, the program does not respond. Is there a way to fix this? I am using the raspberry pi OS on a pi zero w.

[UPDATE]

After running it through CLI at boot, I get this error.

```
[   46.310574] rc.local[410]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   46.321574] rc.local[410]:   File "/home/pi/lcd/CC.py", line 19, in <module>
[   46.323975] rc.local[410]:     activate = input("")
[   46.326199] rc.local[410]:  EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It's implied here that you mean it just prints things and then reads from standard input but the reads _____?  Does it ask all the questions but not take any answers (ie., the reads are empty)?  Or just it just stall or fail at the first question?  Or is my assumption about what you mean incorrect?  How (**exactly and explicity**) are you starting the program?  The problem with too much high level abstraction when you have a problem like this that you cannot solve yourself is that the high level abstract description amounts to an *assumption* about what is happening....

Comment: ...You need to instead *describe in empirical detail* the problem with as little of your own interpretation as possible, include as appropriate actual code snippets, etc. (eg., again, all of `rc.local` verbatim).  **If this is actually a GUI application, that is important.** Details!  We don't know what you are talking about and you have not said much.

Comment: @goldilocks Ok I have added more information, could you reopen my question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Following instructions on this post I got it working.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168415/raspbian-python-script-eof-error-at-startup

Just make sure you boot to CLI.

Go to:

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc
```

and add this to the end of the script:

```
echo Running at boot
sudo python3 /home/pi/filename.py
```

Comment: This will run `sudo python3 /home/pi/filename.py` **whenever you start a shell! This includes GUI terminals!** (I know you said `Just make sure you boot to CLI.` but this is not how you are supposed to use `.bashrc`)

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino You can hit Ctrl C if you need the shell, which I won't for this project.

Answer (score 2):

Starting a service with rc.local has a number of problems:

1. If something you run in rc.local gets stuck, then your system will hang during boot
2. By default, things run from rc.local can’t output anywhere; so you can’t see any errors or other output
3. There’s no “lifetime management”. rc.local runs once and once only.

   1. If you want to run it again, you have to reboot.
   2. If you want to stop something which was started by rc.local, you need to find its process manually and kill it.

I would recommend that you take a look at systemd. There is great guide at:

https://blog.usedbytes.com/2019/11/run-at-startup-without-rc.local/

I've created a systemd service:

```
pi@ubitcluster:~ $ cat /etc/systemd/system/cluster-bit.service 
[Unit]
Description=Toggle LED by pressing the 1 key

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/stack_overflow/ask_input.py
```

That runs a simple service that asks for an input:

```py
#! /home/pi/deployed/venv/bin/python3
import ubit_cluster
hat = ubit_cluster.UbitCluster()
print('test')
device = int(input('device: '))
if device == 1:
    print(hat.p1._pwr.state(0))
    if hat.p1._pwr.state(0):
        print(f'device off')
        hat.p1.off()
    else:
        print(f'device on')
        hat.p1.on()
```

I had `journalctl -f` running in a different window and I could see straight away that the python input command is not a blocking and it continues through and exits.

```
Sep 20 14:17:14 ubitcluster ask_input.py[6357]: test
Sep 20 14:17:14 ubitcluster ask_input.py[6357]: device: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 20 14:17:14 ubitcluster ask_input.py[6357]:   File "/home/pi/stack_overflow/ask_input.py", line 6, in <module>
Sep 20 14:17:14 ubitcluster ask_input.py[6357]:     device = int(input('device: '))
Sep 20 14:17:14 ubitcluster ask_input.py[6357]: EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Sep 20 14:17:14 ubitcluster systemd[1]: cluster-bit.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 20 14:17:14 ubitcluster systemd[1]: cluster-bit.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So I rewrote the code to use the [evdev](https://pypi.org/project/evdev/) library which reads keyboard events:

```py
#! /home/pi/deployed/venv/bin/python3
import ubit_cluster
import asyncio
from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes

hat = ubit_cluster.UbitCluster()
dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event0')

print('test')
print(dev)

def toggle_led():
    print(hat.p1._pwr.state(0))
    if hat.p1._pwr.state(0):
        print(f'device off')
        hat.p1.off()
    else:
        print(f'device on')
        hat.p1.on()


async def helper(dev):
    async for ev in dev.async_read_loop():
        if ev.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
            key_data= categorize(ev)
            print(key_data.keycode)
            if key_data.keystate and key_data.keycode == 'KEY_1':
                print('toggle')
                toggle_led()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(helper(dev))
```

This now toggles the LED when I press key `1` on the attached keyboard.

Comment: WRT #2: You might be able to see output if you don't use a graphical boot, but it will be interleaved with other boot messages.  *You definitely won't be able to accept input from the user because the process does not have the foreground.*  If you want to start something to replace (or precede) the login prompt, `rc.local` is not the way to do it.

Comment: @ukBaz So your saying that I need to start it with systemd  and then the keyboard will work?

Comment: @UNKNOWN: There is so much in your script that it is hard to predict where it might be failing. Moving to systemd will allow you to test if it is working by restarting the service. It will also allow you to view the output from your script starting up. My expectation is that you will update your question with that output and maybe at that point people might be able to help.

Comment: @ukBaz My script fails at "activate = input("")" when the keyboard is required to proceed.

Comment: @UNKNOWN: Updated my answer....

Comment: @UNKNOWN: P.S. Putting `EOFError: EOF when reading a line rc.local` into a search engine results in a few interesting answers. Did none of them help? https://www.google.com/search?q=EOFError%3A+EOF+when+reading+a+line+rc.local&rlz=1CAZBMY_enGB857&oq=EOFError%3A+EOF+when+reading+a+line+rc.local

Comment: @ukBaz Thank you for suggesting that